# react-native-camera build error on android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-camera, camera-view

Hi I'm using the following stack:
 - react-native-camera 1.1.1
 - react-native 0.55.3
 - gradle 3.1.2

I did all the steps described in the docs for linking the project (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera).

The gradle sync ends successfully, but when I try to build the project i get a lot of errors:

```
/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/src/main/java/org/reactnative/camera/RNCameraView.java:15: error: package com.google.android.cameraview does not exist
```

import com.google.android.cameraview.CameraView;

The other errors look the same (CameraView not found)...

Here my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-languages')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    compile (project(':react-native-camera')) {
        compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.+'
        compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
            force = true
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by excluding com.android.support from react-native-camera:

```
compile (project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        exclude group: "com.android.support" // --> this line
        compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.+'
        compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1') {
            force = true
        }
    }
```